# Haskell - Mapping a function over a Rose Tree

Tags: haskell, tree

If I define a Rose tree as

```
data RTree = Node a [RTree a]
    deriving(Show, Eq)
```

How would I go about defining a map function for it? The map function is to be  defined as

```
map_rose_tree :: (a -> b) -> RTree a -> RTree b
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to enable the `DeriveFunctor` extension and `derive Functor`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data RTree a
    = Node a [RTree a]
    deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)

map_rose_tree = fmap
```

But if you wanted to define the instance yourself you'll need to pattern match on the `RTree` constructor:

```
instance Functor RTree where
    fmap f (Node a children) = Node _ _
```

You'll have to fill in the two `_` yourself.  If you have a new enough version of GHC, you can compile this and get errors telling you the types of the holes (`_`) along with relevant bindings that you can use to implement it.  The first hole is pretty easy, the second one is a little more challenging, but I assure you it can be solved with only `fmap`, `f`, `a`, and `children`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about mapping over the list component of the rose tree. Could you offer a nudge in the right direction for that component please?

Comment: @vs9734 You know that `children :: [RTree a]`, and you want to get `[RTree b]`.  You have a function `fmap :: (a -> b) -> RTree a -> RTree b` and `f :: a -> b`, so `fmap f :: RTree a -> RTree b`.  How would you apply this to every element of a list?

Comment: I thought I would use the map function but I keep getting errors, no matter what combination I use. I'm going to need you to be more explicit please. I very new to Haskell.

Comment: @vs9734 What combinations have you tried?  Me being more explicit would basically involve me giving you the answer, so I'd like to see where you're stuck first.  If I know that then I can give you more useful advice that will help you avoid these problems in the future instead of just getting the solution now.

Comment: @vs9734 `[RTree a]`, is a nested structure. The outer list `[]` is a functor, and the inner `RTree a`s are functors too. You want to map over the `a`s all the way inside, 2 levels deep. So how would you do that? You can `fmap` a function over the outer list, right? That would give you access to the inner `RTree a`s. Now what if that function you map *also* calls fmap?